# Show C# Array on user request

Tags: c#, arrays

I need a way to get the response from a user.

For example they type "hat" and it displays the price in the array table in a console writeline. It also needs to be done in a 2d array instead of dictionary

```
 class Table
{
    string[,] names = {
                      {"rice", "50"}, 
                      {"chip", "20"}, 
                      {"hat", "50"}, 
                      {"ball", "34"}, 
                      };
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Res;
        Console.WriteLine("What product would you like?");
        Res = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you not using a Dictionary<string, string> ?

Comment: This is not a valid question. What's preventing you from finishing your program? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints first.

Comment: Please keep in mind the OP has 1 reputation and may just be starting out.  They may not have mastered the terminology necessary to ask an "expert level question".  Considering this question is not an advanced question I assume the OP is not an expert C# programmer.  Beginners should be able to get advice on SO assuming their question makes sense.  This one is certainly answerable.

Comment: The assignment requires use of a 2d array table using columns and rows, and then asking the user for a string and displaying the price of it. I cannot use dictionary.

Comment: Then question was really in "How to find value in 2d array and return it?" rather than "Show C# Array...", wasn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary<string, string>` rather that way you can look up the `Value` based on the `Key`

```
Dictionary<string, string> example = new Dictionary<string, string>();
example.Add("hat", "50");
//Add the rest in this manner
```

The you can do the lookup like this

```
 if (example.ContainsKey(Res))
    string price = example[Res];
```

Comment: I need to use a 2d array in this instance rather than a dictionary unfortunately

Comment: @user2980622 - Is this to meet a requirement for homework?

Answer (score 1):

**Straightforward solution with 2-d array:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var products = new[,] { {"rice", "50"}, {"chip", "20"}, {"hat", "50"}, {"ball", "34"} }; 

        Console.WriteLine("What product would you like?");
        var request = Console.ReadLine();

        string value = null;
        if (request != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < products.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                if (products[i, 0] == request)
                {
                    value = products[i, 1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've  selected: " + request + ". Value is: " + value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've  selected: " + request + ". No value found.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using a Dictionary instead of your jagged array. It is better and you get more flexibility.

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, string>(5); 
items.Add("rice", "50");
items.Add("chip", "20");
// and so on
```

then you get the item by checking to see if the key exists first:

```
if (items.ContainsKey("rice"))
{
   // it exists! read it:
   Console.WriteLine(items["rice"]);
}
```